# Unpack string column with multiple dictionaries in PySpark

Tags: json, dictionary, pyspark, databricks, flatten

In Databricks, using PySpark, I am working on a DataFrame that has the following column, where each row is a list with multiple dictionaries:
[image]

[image]

I would like to unpack/flatten this column, so that there is a separate column for each of the dictionary values.
However, the issue is that the data type of this column is a string.
How can I unpack the column?

For reference, here is an example of a value:

> [{"long_name":"Sofia","short_name":"Sofia","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Sofia City Province","short_name":"Sofia City Province","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"Bulgaria","short_name":"BG","types":["country","political"]}]

Comment: Could you please provide the feedback of why have you decided to uncheck the question as answered?

Answer (score 1):

Your string column can be converted to array of structs using [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#from_json) and providing the schema. Then you can do [`inline`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#inline) to explode it to columns.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('[{"long_name":"Sofia","short_name":"Sofia","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Sofia City Province","short_name":"Sofia City Province","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"Bulgaria","short_name":"BG","types":["country","political"]}]',)],
    ['address_components'])

df = df.selectExpr(
    "inline(from_json(address_components, 'array<struct<long_name:string,short_name:string,types:array<string>>>'))"
)

df.show(truncate=0)
# +-------------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------+
# |long_name          |short_name         |types                                   |
# +-------------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------+
# |Sofia              |Sofia              |[locality, political]                   |
# |Sofia City Province|Sofia City Province|[administrative_area_level_1, political]|
# |Bulgaria           |BG                 |[country, political]                    |
# +-------------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------+
```